# Sql joins returning Null Results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables that i am trying to get data from yet my join statement returns null. I have tried full, left and right joins with no success. Blow i have provided my code and the diagram, the table that returns null values is the ChannelData table. i am trying to sum the Vvalue from this table:

```
DECLARE @bp varchar(4)
DECLARE @priority varchar(2)
DECLARE @startDate datetime
DECLARE @endDate datetime

SET @bp = 1710
SET @priority = 2

SET @endDate = (SELECT EndDate FROM BillingPeriod WHERE BillingPeriodClass_ID = 1 AND CODE = @BP)
SET @startDate = (SELECT EndDate FROM BillingPeriod WHERE BillingPeriodClass_ID = 1 AND CODE = @BP -1 )
SET @startDate = dateadd(minute, 1, @startDate)


SELECT  CGS.Description,
        CD.VValue, DI.Margin, @priority AS PRIORITY

FROM DataIntegrity AS DI

FULL JOIN CGS AS CGS ON CGS.ID = DI.CGS_ID_1 OR CGS.ID = DI.CGS_ID_2 
LEFT JOIN ChannelParameter AS CP ON CP.ID = CGS.ID
LEFT JOIN ChannelData AS CD ON CP.ID = CD.ID AND DI.CGS_ID_1 = CD.ID AND DI.CGS_ID_2 = CD.ID

where DI.Priority = @priority

 group by CGS.Description, CD.VValue,  DI.Margin
```

Results

[image]

db_diagram

[image]

another example where i tried this query getting null values when including the Report table in stead of the DI table:

[second result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bqaV.png)

```
SELECT SUM(CD.VValue),  CGS.Description,
SUM(CD.VValue)

FROM CGS AS CGS

FULL JOIN ChannelParameter AS CP ON CP.ID = CGS.ID
FULL JOIN ChannelData AS CD ON CP.ID = CD.ID
FULL JOIN Report AS R on R.CGS_ID = CGS.ID

where -- CD.DDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate 
             r.Description = 'rEGION EP'

 group by CGS.Description, CD.VValue'
```

Comment: This looks strange. A column called ID should be the table's unique ID, i.e. uniquely identifying a record in the table. We see, that the table `CGS` has such an ID. And there is a table `DataIntegrity` combining two CGS records via their IDs. There is also a table called `Report` containing reports per CGS, for `CGS_ID` is part of its key. But what about the table `ChannelParameter`? There is a line connecting it with the `CGS` table, but it doesn't contain a column `CGS_ID`, nor does `CGS` contain a column called `ChannelParameter_ID` it seems (or we just cannot see it). ...

Comment: You join the two tables on their IDs. Are you trying to establish an {1}:{1} relation here? Or a {0-1}:{1} relation or even a {0-1}:{0-1} relation? Or is this just an error? And the table `ChannelData` has `ID` as part of its primary key. What ID is this? Obviously not the table's ID in spite of its name. So maybe the `CGS_ID`? Or rather the `ChannelParameter_ID`?

Comment: `DI.CGS_ID_1 = CD.ID AND DI.CGS_ID_2 = CD.ID` looks suspicious. Should it be `(DI.CGS_ID_1 = CD.ID OR DI.CGS_ID_2 = CD.ID)`?

Comment: Unfortunately you posted information on your deleted answer that you haven't added to your request. You said: "Yes the ID columns are really CGS_ID in the CP and CD tables. So each CGS must have atleast one or many CPs". But from the diagram it looks like `ID` is primary key in `ChannelParameter`. How then can one CGS have multiple CPs? Or is this an error in the diagram? Can there be multiple records for one `ID` in `ChannelParameter`? And a CGS with zero CPs would be considered invalid, yes?

Comment: There is an error with the database, the id in cp is in fact a foreign key which in in cgs it is  a primary key, this database is an old one and belongs to the company i work for so yes whoever created it did not set the keys and ids correctly but i have to work with what i have. i am sorry this is my first time posting on stackoverflow excuse me for not updating my request correctly. all i need is a way to get data from the cd table for only ids in the di table and as you see above i joined the cp table since its the only table that has a relationship with the CD table.

Comment: i hope this makes more sense as to what i want to do. i have already tried choosing a specific record to test the joins but i can read from all table except the cd table

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess the problem is in the join:

```
 LEFT JOIN ChannelData AS CD ON CP.ID = CD.ID AND DI.CGS_ID_1 = CD.ID AND DI.CGS_ID_2 = CD.ID
```

Elsewhere you're using a join on CGS_ID_1 **OR** CGS_ID_2, in this clause you're doing it with **AND**. Is this correct?

Also CP.ID = CD.ID looks suspect. It looks like a join from a primary key to a primary key instead of a primary key to a foreign key.

Comment: I overlooked that i was just playing around with the code to see what would happen but it was initially just: "LEFT JOIN ChannelData AS CD ON CP.ID = CD.ID"

Comment: I just need to get a result set with vvalue accumulated if i ommit the DI table  and join the data vvalue accumulates but once i try join the di table to the query or work with it then my results are null. i have included another example but this time with the report table:

Comment: The issue is going to be data related - you need to check each join individually to work out where it's falling over. From the nature of the problem and the naming of the fields my best guess is that one of the joins going from ID to ID is wrong. Normally a primary key field named ID is going to be the primary key for that table rather than one that refers to another table.

Test CP.ID = CD.ID and CP.ID = CD.ID carefully to make sure they are working how you would expect.

Comment: I understand that those work as expected i can join the CP, CD, AND CGS tables and get all data, problem only arises when i involve the DI or Report table in the query the ID field is the is a foreign key and the relationships are fine... its only a matter of getting data from all tables.

Comment: In your examples when you've added the DI or Report table you've then filtered on an item in those tables. Have you tried picking a random record that meets your criteria from those tables and checking table by table that there are joins from there to ChannelData? I really think the issue here is in your joins somewhere. e: you could try adding a field from each table to the select clause in the second query to check that all tables are joining correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, merly joining tables is not the solution. First of all, it is often recommended or even necessary to aggregate first and join the aggregate rather than first joining the tables and aggregate then.

Then, when we merely want to check whether values in a table exist, we usually want this as criteria in the `WHERE` clause, rather than in a join.

And sometimes we want to combine data sets with `UNION ALL` (or sometimes with `UNION`).

**First query: The vvallue sum per CGS, margin and priority.** Well, a CGS can have multiple margins and priorities, so we'll have to find these first. As the table in question has a CGS_ID_1 and a CGS_ID_2, we'll use `UNION` in order to get margins and priorities per CGS. Then, the vvalue has nothing to do with margin and priority; it's merely a sum per CGS, so it is going to be repeated in the results.

```
select cgs.description, di.margin, di.priority, coalesce(sum_vvalue, 0) as total
from cgs
join
(
  select cgs_id_1 as cgs_id, margin, priority from dataintegrity
  union
  select cgs_id_1 as cgs_id, margin, priority from dataintegrity
) di on di.cgs_id = cgs.id and di.priority = @priority
left join
(
  select id as cgs_id, sum(vvalue) as sum_vvalue
  from channeldata
  group by id
) cd on cd.cgs_id = cgs.id
order by cgs.description, di.margin, di.priority;
```

**Secons query: The vvallue sum per CGS for a certain region.** There can be many reports per CGS and we'll have to find all CGS with reports in the desired region. This is a mere lookup, which should be done with `IN` or `EXISTS`.

```
select cgs.description, coalesce(sum_vvalue, 0) as total
from cgs
left join
(
  select id as cgs_id, sum(vvalue) as sum_vvalue
  from channeldata
  group by id
) cd on cd.cgs_id = di.cgs_id
where cgs.id in (select cgs_id from report where description = 'REGION EP')
order by cgs.description;
```